# Filtering discrete data

Tags: lowpass-filter

Is is possible to use a digital filter (eg. Butterworth) for smoothing sensor data that is sampled at a non-constant rate? The time between two consecutive samples is between 12 to 40 ms.

Comment: Do you have proper time-stamps of you samples? Or is it a huge jitter problem?

Comment: I have proper time-stamps.

Comment: Do you know anything about the bandwidth of the data you are sampling? Also, is the data processed in any way before the sensor reads it?

Answer (score 1):

The most naive and easiest method would be to interpolate the data points. If you know what is the maximum frequency present in your signal then you can specify the sampling period. Let's say you pick the lowest possible: **12ms**. Now you can perform some interpolation of your data. Normally I would suggest you to perform the sinc interpolation, but you can start with linear/spline/cubic.

In MATLAB/Octave you can use the `interp1` function to interpolate the data points. If your data is called `x`, known time stamps are `t`, and new time stamps are `t_new`, then you can do the following to calculate new dataset `X`:

```
t_new = 0:0.012:max(t); %spaced by 12ms up to maximum value of vector t
X = interp1(t, x, t_new, 'spline');
```

This is very simple approach but should work - although you might get some aliasing. You can also check out this article for more intelligent methods: [Nonuniform Sampling and Reconstruction in Shift-Invariant Spaces](http://mate.dm.uba.ar/~hafg/papers-sem-05/al-gr-review.pdf).

Now when you have your dataset, you can perform any filtering you like. Can I ask you what your sensor is so it's providing such data?